# If you wire together two TTL outputs, which one wins?

Tags: digital-logic, ttl

If you connect together two outputs from 7400 NAND gates, which output will dominate - high or low?

Background: I'm reverse-engineering a 1969 circuit board, and in multiple cases they tie together two outputs from 7400 NAND gates, presumably to make a wired-OR. This would be reasonable if they used open-collector chips, but these are SN7400N chips, so it seems a bit sketchy. (In other places, they leave an input floating, presumably to high, which also seems sketchy.)

Comment: you are asking the wrong question .... you need to be asking `which output did the designer intend to win?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The low one wins, TTL outouts have a stronger pull down than their pull up.

TTL inputs are current sources so they float high naturally.

[image: TTL Nor gate]

when high there's 130 ohms and a diode between VCC and the output pin.
that's going to limit the high-state output current to about 25mA

Combining outputs in this way will hurt performance, the device will produce more heat and probably be slower than if you used actual and gates to combine their outputs, bit if the main goal is to use fewer parts this can be a win.

Comment: In other words, this isn't sketchy at all. It would be if they were 74C or 74HC or something, but 74, 74S, 74LS, and I think also 74F are all fine to use like this. Inputs reliably float high and outputs drive low much more strongly than they drive high.

Comment: THe output impedance is non-linear but at rated TTL V levels Iol is 20x Ioh

Comment: With the understanding that normally analog and digital inputs are NOT left floating.

Comment: with any logic family, including TTL, wire-ORing outputs (other than open collector/drain or OE types) is sketchy, even if the low type in known to win, as it degrades margins, and draws excess current. With TTL (but not CMOS) leaving inputs open is OK, as they are current sosurces.